# DynamoDB returning an error 400 on HTTP.post

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

Not sure what's going on with the code but I'm working with Playfab Cloud Scripts which is essentially just Javascript that you can't reference outside libraries in. I've included the source code for this    https://gist.github.com/ryanjduffy/4686906

to be able to do encryption but something is wrong with the signature. I've ensured that I'm using the corrected AccessKey and SecretKey multiple times. My only thought is that I'm generating the signature incorrectly somewhere.

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
var kDate = HMAC_SHA256_MAC(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
var kRegion = HMAC_SHA256_MAC(regionName, kDate);
var kService = HMAC_SHA256_MAC(serviceName, kRegion);
var kSigning = HMAC_SHA256_MAC("aws4_request", kService);
return kSigning;
}

handlers.DynamoRequest = function (args, context) {
   var method = "POST";
   var service = "dynamodb";
   var host = "dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";
var region = "us-east-2";
var target = "DynamoDB_20120810.PutItem";
var contentType = "application/json";
var signedHeaders = "content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target";
var algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
var accessKey = "keyInsertedHere";
var secretKey = "keyInsertedHere";

var date = new Date().toISOString();
date = date.split("-").join("");
date = date.split(":").join("");
date = date.substring(0, 15);
date = date + "Z";

var body = {
"TableName": "PlayerItems",
"Key": {
"PlayerID": {"S": "id1"}
}
};

body = JSON.stringify(body);

var canonicalHeaders = 'content-type:' + contentType + '\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + date + '\n' + 'x-amz-target:' + target + '\n';

var payloadHash = SHA256_hash(body);
var canonicalRequest = method + "\n" + "/" + "\n" + "" + "\n" + canonicalHeaders + "\n" + signedHeaders + "\n" + payloadHash;

var credentialScope = date.substring(0, 8) + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/" + "aws4_request";
var stringToSign = algorithm + "\n" +  date + "\n" +  credentialScope + "\n" +  SHA256_hash(canonicalRequest);
var signingKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, date.substring(0, 8), region, service); 
var signature = HMAC_SHA256_MAC(signingKey, stringToSign);
var authHeader = algorithm + " " + "Credential=" + accessKey + "/" + credentialScope + ", " +  "SignedHeaders=" + signedHeaders + ", " + "Signature=" + signature;

var headers = {
"Content-Type": contentType,
"Host": host,
"X-Amz-Target": target,
"X-Amz-Date": date,
"Authorization": authHeader
};

try{
var response = http.request("https://" + host, method, body, contentType, headers, true);   
return { responseContent: response };
}
catch(e){
return {error: e};
}
};
```

Comment: The result of running this is an invalidSignatureException. I need to figure out where I'm going wrong with my encryption or the signature setup...